# нахождения всех ключей в объекте

Tags: javascript

Добрых времени суток, есть такая задача: необходимо написать функцию для обработки ключей объекта. Функция должна принимать два аргумента:

1. Объект/Массив, ключи которого необходимо конвертировать;
2. Формат, в который необходимо преобразовать ключи (uppercase, lowercase);

На данный момент на 2-ой пункт можно не обращать внимания (но кому очень интересно - буду рад решению), вот что имею:

```js
const obj = [{
  "key1": 1,
  "key2": "hello_world",
  "key3": {
    "key4": {
      "key5": [{
        "key6": "hello_world",
        "key7": {
          "key8": 2
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}];

const keys = [];

const fn = obj => {
  Object.keys({...obj}).forEach(key => {
    if (typeof obj[key] == 'object') {
      keys.push(key);
      fn(obj[key]);
    } else {
      keys.push(key);
    }
  });

  return keys;
}

console.log(fn(obj))
```

Вопросы:

1. Как избежать `'0'` в выходном объекте?
2. Каким образом можно перенести `keys` в саму функцию? (пытался через замыкание, но не вышло);

Если кто возьмётся помочь, то, если не затруднит, как можно подробнее объяснить поведение.

Comment: @OPTIMUSPRIME, спасибо за комментарий, каким образом можно "пропустить" ключ массива? Но вставить ключ объекта, под ключом массива и пойти дальше по циклу...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Число `0` возникает из-за того, что массивы в JS - на самом деле объекты с числовыми ключами:

```js
console.log( Object.keys( ["My", "test", "array"] ) );
```

Перед `push` надо проверять, не являлся ли объект массивом. Для этого существует или `Array.isArray(obj)` или `obj instanceof Array` → https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray

```js
const obj = [{
  "tEsTcAmEl1": 1,
  "key2": "hello_world",
  "key3": {
    "key4": {
      "key5": [{
        "key6": "hello_world",
        "key7": {
          "key8": 2
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}];

console.log( deepObjectKeys(obj, 'upper') );

/*****/

function deepObjectKeys(obj, letterCase) {
  let cases = {
    "upper": key => key.toUpperCase(),
    "lower": key => key.toLowerCase(),
  };
  let setCase = cases[letterCase] || ( key => key );
                                  // throw new Error('???');
  
  let keyStorage = [];
  storeKeysRecursive(obj);

  return keyStorage;

  /***/

  function storeKeysRecursive(obj) {
    if (obj instanceof Object) {
      let notArrayKey = !Array.isArray(obj);
      
      Object.keys({...obj}).forEach(key => {
        if (notArrayKey) keyStorage.push( setCase(key) );
        
        return storeKeysRecursive( obj[key] );
      })
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const obj = [{
  "key1": 1,
  "key2": "hello_world",
  "key3": {
    "key4": {
      "key5": [{
        "key6": "hello_world",
        "key7": {
          "key8": 2
        }
      }]
    }
  }
}];

const fn = obj => {
  const keys = [];
  Object.keys({...obj}).forEach(key => {
    if (typeof obj[key] == 'object') {
      if(!Array.isArray(obj)) keys.push(key); //(1)
      keys.push(...fn(obj[key])); //(2)
    } else  {
      keys.push(key);
    }
  });
  return keys;
}

console.log(fn(obj))
```

Не знаю смог ли я объяснить?

1. 0 появляется потому-что это **ключ массива**(0, 1, 2, ...), поэтому я просто сделал проверку, если это не массив то пушить ключ;
2. Чтобы keys была в функции, причем через рекурсию, надо чтобы рекурсивная функция **вернула результат работы**, и все понятно, она вернёт массив, нужно его раскрыть, а потом естественно добавить в массив там где была вызвана рекурсия.

Звучит сложно только в тексте, но если представить в голове все станет ясно.